# Will swapping a dw01a for a dw01a-g

Tags: power-supply, lipo

I am designing a circuit for my charity in honour of my stepson who passed away aged 2.
I know so much but sometimes get stuck.
I am designing the PCB half myself and then half a lipo charger from another person's project.
Now what I am trying to do is make sure all components are stocked by lcsl.com.
The dw01a is discontinued on there (the specific one used).
Can I swap this out for a dw01a-g?

Sorry for such a simple noob question

Many thanks

Comment: Please link the datasheets and check your part numbers. Do you mean this [DW01+G](https://lcsc.com/mobile/product-detail/Battery-Protection-ICs_DW01-G_C14213.html)? You should also post the details of the charging circuit you want to use. You should be able to link this easily since you're using "someone else's project." At a glance - I could be wrong - the "+G" is just a green packaging code.

Comment: @type both the dw01a and dw01a-g are valid part numbers.

Comment: @Passerby I didn't see the DW01A-G on LCSC but it is there, I missed it. I do think OP should link the parts though.

Answer (score 3):

[LSCS is one of the best suppliers](https://lcsc.com/products/Battery-Management-ICs_612.html?keyword=dw01) of these Taiwanese chips.
There is greater stock and wider variety.

The suffix differences are significant but acceptable in your case.

[image]

All the G's are Green meaning RoHS meaning lead-free.

I could suggest + or -  which differ by only +/- 50 mV.  "+" gives slightly more capacity at the expense of charge cycle lives.  Generally, lower voltage "-" is a more cost-effective use of batteries.

The "C-G" suffix is what I recommend, but A-G is what you asked for is OK.

Answer (score 1):

The two are either the same part but renumbered due to expanded features of other variations, or slightly similar.

If you are working from scratch then look at the datasheets for both and decide if they are drop in identical or similar enough you can adapt it.

You have to make sure your using the datasheet for the specific manufacturer version of the dw01 you are looking to use. These cloned chips can have differences between manufacturers.